# How do I make my monitors show up as two separate monitors? - NVidia GeForce GTX 550 ti

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, wacom

I've got a dual-monitor setup, with the monitors configured through the "Nvidia X Server Settings" application.

In the Ubuntu Display settings, the monitors show up as one extra-wide monitor labelled "Laptop". Until now, this really hasn't been a problem, but now I'm trying to set up a Wacom tablet.

The Ubuntu tablet settings allow the tablet to be mapped to a specific monitor, but since the OS "thinks" that I have only one monitor, I can only map the tablet to both of them.

This is a problem. Is there any way to have Ubuntu recognize the monitors separately?

Comment: Try "clone output" in the "nvidia-settings" manager. This will make both displays to be merged as one piece and the wacom tablet will map to only one monitor.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of having two monitors, would it not?

Comment: Oh sorry. I understood you wish to have just one monitor, which is the case as for the Compaq CQ1 which somehow features an all-in-one layout with the embedded monitor and a "secondary" monitor in the same layout. I am editing an answer which may be helpful for you. Thank you and sorry for the misunderstood, my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use xsetwacom to map the stylus to a specific region of your large desktop. If you use xorg.conf you can have it automatically map the tablet at login using topx, topy, bottomx, and bottomy; or you can make a startup script to run at login. The linuxwacom man page has information on how to calculate the numbers you'll need for topx, topy, bottomx, and bottomy.